# Upload 20000+ photos to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, upload

I would like to upload 20000+ photos to OneDrive through web.
But when I try to upload folder or files, OneDrive is stuck and no file is uploaded.

Is there any limit on how much files I can upload?

Comment: One drive limit is 10GB, how many GB is all your photos? Do you receive any error messages? Have you tried basic trouble shooting, like check if you can upload one file, then try a folder with 10 files, then with a thousand files?

Comment: I have new account with 1TB free space, photos have approximately 100GB so it shouldn't be a problem. I am able to upload less files at once but I can't do it like this. I need to upload everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive has an upload limit of 1000 individual files per session, I think user1563721 has come to realize this and has started uploading his/her photos one thousand at a time.

OneDrive chose the thousand limit because it is a limit that will work on most browsers.

As suggested before, if you want to upload 20,000 files at once, try using a desktop sync client rather than a browser, try --> [OneDrive Desktop App](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is an inherent limit to the number of files you can upload. I uploaded my entire phone directory to oneDrive without a hitch before.

However, since you are using the web interface instead of an application, this could be the problem with how oneDrive is implemented online or the browser in question.

If you are simply looking to archive the files, try archiving them in .zip or .rar format. This way oneDrive has to only handle one large file. In many cases, this makes the transfer quicker too.

Comment: I don't want to zip all photos, I would like to have them on OneDrive. I tried different browsers without any success. It seems that I would end by uploading 20 times 1000 photos which seems to be working.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used OneDrive myself but this is what they say in its website

> There's a 10-gigabyte (GB) file size limit for each file that's uploaded to the OneDrive for Business library.

source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3125202

**edit** In the past people had limitation of 20.000 files, but this limitation was removed by Microsoft. I would suggest to try installing the OneDrive client [here](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/) since you are using the web interface.

Comment: This answer doesn't really seem to actually answer the question.

Comment: Your comment doesn't really seem to actually help to answer the question.

Comment: You write about a file size limit, however unlikely that he would have photos with 10 GB file size.

Comment: The question is about uploading 20000+ photos. He is not asking about filesize limits, but the amount of files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/577164)